# Get first Http response from Parallel

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have 5 URL and I want to make a Http request for each one, And waiting for the first response that has the conditions.

```
List<string> urls; // url1, url2, ......

ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.ForEach(urls, url=> GetTimeSlot(url));

private string GetTimeSlot(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)).ReadToEnd();
        if (responseString.Length < 6)
            return "";   //PARALEL RESUME
        else
            return responseString;   //PARALEL ENDS
}
```

**I need only the first response**. Is it possible with Parallel or is there any better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel.ForEach will be fine to use especially for your use case.Just use a cancellation token to stop all other running tasks.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var _lock = new Object();
        var po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
        var listOfUrls = new List<string>() { "url1", "url2" };
        var responsResult = "";
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(listOfUrls, po, (url) =>
            {
                po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
                string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)).ReadToEnd();

                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (responseString.Length > 6)
                    {
                       responsResult = responseString;
                        cts.Cancel();
                    }                        
                }           

            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            //cancellation was requested
        }
        finally
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a lock to make it sure no other thread is updating the result. The thrown OperationCanceledException is what you would expect, when you call cts.Cancel(); If it is an other exception but OperationCanceledException  it means something went wrong with your  WebRequest.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. It worked!! I'm going to test `lock`.

Comment: What is the `_lock` ? `The name lock is not exists...` error i got.

Comment: I don't think the `responsResult = "";` statement should be there, that makes that you still have a race-condition despite the lock. Just drop that line.

Comment: you are right just updated the solution, that code was redundant any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PLinq:

```
string firstResponse = urls
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(url => GetTimeSlot(url))
    .FirstOrDefault(r => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(r))                
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you @Henk.  Does it cancel operations when i get the first response?

Comment: It will not cancel anything but it will not start new ones either. Whatever is already running will complete. In vain.